Unable to access Gateway Details using PowerBi API
I'm working on a small task where I have to fetch gateway detail of the PowerBi Datasets using an API. We are using PowerShell scripts to fetch the data.
I'm able to access the Datasets and Other details but when I modify the script to access the Gateway details I'm getting the following error:
+ ...  $gatewaydata = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $gatewayuri -Method Get  
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
CategoryInfo          : WriteError: >(Microsoft.Power...werBIRestMethod:InvokePowerBIRestMethod) [Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod], Exception
FullyQualifiedErrorId : Encountered errors when invoking the command: {
   "code": "PowerBINotAuthorizedException",
   "pbi.error": {
     "code": "PowerBINotAuthorizedException",
     "parameters": {},
     "details": [],
     "exceptionCulprit": 1
   }
 },Microsoft.PowerBI.Commands.Profile.InvokePowerBIRestMethod

When I checked the App registration for the API I can see that PowerBi API has the access related to gateway enabled.
How to resolve this issue?
I had given all the app related details like appId, appsecret and executed it. I was expecting the gateway details but got error saying:

"PowerBINotAuthorizedException"

